# Use having and order by in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I would want to select the elements of the column `sanciones.matricula_vehiculo` that appear more than once,  the next code shows all the elements; but would lack a restricion similiar to > 1

```
SELECT 
vehiculos.marca_vehiculo, 
sanciones.matricula_vehiculo, 
vehiculos.modelo_vehiculo

FROM vehiculos
INNER JOIN sanciones
ON vehiculos.matricula_vehiculo=sanciones.matricula_vehiculo
ORDER BY vehiculos.marca_vehiculo;
```

Comment: Just a little tip for posting problems: try to simplify your question as much as possible. There's really no reason to use compicated column and table names like you did here. It just obscures your question and makes it harder for us to read the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT marca_vehiculo, matricula_vehiculo, modelo_vehiculo
FROM (SELECT v.marca_vehiculo, s.matricula_vehiculo, v.modelo_vehiculo,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY s.matricula_vehiculo) as cnt
      FROM vehiculos v INNER JOIN
           sanciones s
           ON v.matricula_vehiculo = s.matricula_vehiculo
     ) vs
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY marca_vehiculo;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT matricula_vehiculo
FROM vehiculos
INNER JOIN sanciones ON vehiculos.matricula_vehiculo=sanciones.matricula_vehiculo
GROUP BY matricula_vehiculo
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY vehiculos.marca_vehiculo
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too, and you will not have the overhead of a JOIN by using EXISTS:

```
SELECT 
    vehiculos.marca_vehiculo, 
    vehiculos.matricula_vehiculo, 
    vehiculos.modelo_vehiculo
FROM vehiculos v
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT *
                FROM sanciones s 
                WHERE s.matricula_vehiculo = v.matricula_vehiculo
                HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 )
ORDER BY vehiculos.marca_vehiculo;
```